# docker-compose cron job not executing

Tags: docker

## Issue:

### cron job

```
@reboot cd ~ && docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d >> $HOME/containerLog.txt 2>&1
```

### grepCron /var/log/syslog

```
May 30 07:39:01 omitted CRON[9584]: (omitted) CMD (cd ~ && docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d >> $HOME/containerLog.txt 2>&1)
```

So cron job and deamons do run because the bellow cronjob executes as expected:

```
* * * * * echo "Hello world" > ~/hw.txt
```

docker also works fine, as if executed manually the above command runs fine.

### /etc/crontab path and script:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
```

### system info

ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64bit

The job is logged as executed, but just nothing happens and the services are not pulled and then restarted.

Answer (score 1):

Hey this might be random but I have been running into this issue months before and again today. Finally, after searching for hours to no avail I found my answer myself:

Since I installed docker as a snap package I had to add the /snap/bin folder to PATH.
There's literally no post that describes this problem, probably because snaps are still not that common. Also, /snap/bin is not added in .bashrc but still in the env.

So in your example that would look something like this:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/snap/bin
```

Maybe that's of any help?
In my setup the command would execute, too, but obviously not find docker.